# Is there an alternative to using 'this' in this code?

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code snippets and would like to know how 'this' is being used as well as if there is another way of doing it with same end result. I tried generating an ArrayList by doing, ArrayList a = new ArrayList();, but it did not include the numbers '1, 2' and only have '4,6'. The output should be '1, 2, 4, 6'.

I am highlighting the code I am asking about:

```
int i = 0;
Sequence a = this;
```

Methods:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Sequence
{
        private ArrayList<Integer> values;
        public Sequence()
        {
            values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

        public void add(int n)
        {
            values.add(n);
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return values.toString();
        }

        public Sequence append(Sequence other)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Sequence a = this;

            while(i < other.values.size())
            {
                a.add(other.values.get(i));

                i++;
            }

            return a;

        }
}
```

Tester/Driver:

```
public class SequenceTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Sequence obj2 = new Sequence();

        obj2.add(4);
        obj2.add(6);


        Sequence obj = new Sequence();

        obj.add(1);
        obj.add(2);

        Sequence append = obj.append(obj2);

        System.out.println(append);
    }


}
```

Comment: Note: You're using K&R-style formatting (e.g., opening brace on a new line). This takes up extra vertical space, and Java has _very_ strong formatting conventions, including "brace on same line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would like to know how 'this' is being used

"this" refers to the current instance of a class.

> if there is another way of doing it with same end result.

There is no need to explicitly create a Sequence variable in the append(...) method.

You can just invoke the add(...) method directly and return "this":

```
    public Sequence append(Sequence other)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //Sequence a = this;

        while(i < other.values.size())
        {
            //a.add(other.values.get(i));
            add(other.values.get(i));

            i++;
        }

        //  return a;
        return this;

    }
```

Methods of the class always operate on the current instance of the class so there is no need to use "this" to get a reference to the class.

Comment: It can make sense to assign `this` to a variable, eg when traverse a linked list from a given node to the end, `Node node = this; while (node != null) {node = node.next;)`